# Check for word in string

Tags: php

What is the best way to search for a word in a string

```
preg_match("/word/",$string)

stripos("word",$string)
```

Or is there a better way

Comment: I think you gave the answer yourself... It would be micro-optimalization if you would use another function to check if the word occurs in the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One benefit to using regexp for this job is the ability to use `\b` ([Regexp word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) in the regexp, and other random derivations.  If you are only looking for that sequence of letters in a string `stripos` is likely to be a *little* better.

```
$tests = array("word", "worded", "This also has the word.", "Words are not the same", "Word capitalized should match");
foreach ($tests as $string)
{
  echo "Testing \"$string\": Regexp:";
  echo preg_match("/\bword\b/i", $string) ? "Matched" : "Failed";
  echo " stripos:";
  echo stripos("word", $string) >= 0 ? "Matched": "Failed";
  echo "\n";
}
```

Results:

```
Testing "word": Regexp:Matched stripos:Matched
Testing "worded": Regexp:Failed stripos:Matched
Testing "This also has the word.": Regexp:Matched stripos:Matched
Testing "Words are not the same": Regexp:Failed stripos:Matched
Testing "Word capitalized should match": Regexp:Matched stripos:Matched
```

Comment: Does this cover hyphenated words like "co-worker" or would "co" match?

Comment: The spot between a `-` and a letter would match for `\b` -- so `\bwork` would match `co-worker` -- You can get more specific with [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 4):

Like it says in the Notes for [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

Comment: strstr() function is case sensitive.

Comment: @Harish so? Use `stristr` or `stripos` if you need case-insensitive.

Comment: but stripos() function will return the position for the alphabet in the string, so its not useful..in the above case.. @Gordon

Comment: @Harish What makes you think that? If `stripos` does not return `FALSE`, it means the searched word is within the string, so it is very much appropriate to use `stripos` for finding out if the word exists within another string (unless you need boundaries). And as I quoted from the PHP Manual, it is also faster than using `preg_match`. You are basically saying, the PHP manual is wrong. If you really think that, please go to the linked manual page and click the [Report A Bug](http://bugs.php.net/report.php?bug_type=Documentation+problem&manpage=function.preg-match%23Notes) Link and tell them.

Comment: no no i got it...just thought it that way...its right.. and thank u, that u explained...actually i got confused with stripos() and strpos() PHP functions...

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply looking for a substring, `stripos()` or `strpos()` and friends are much better than using the `preg` family of functions.

Answer (score 1):

For simple string matching the PHP string functions offer more performance.  Regex is more heavyweight and therefore has lower performance.

Having said that, in most cases, the performance difference is small enough to go unnoticed, unless you're looping over an array with hundreds of thousands of elements or more.

Of course, as soon as you start needing "cleverer" matching, regex becomes the only game in town.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `substr_count($haystack, $needle)` which just returns the number of substring occurences.  With the added bonus of not having to worry about 0 equating to `false` like `stripos()` if the first occurrence is at position 0.  Although that's not a problem if you use strict equality.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php